# C++ boost trying to get the disk usage,capacity from the disk device path

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I am using boost with C++ on Linux.
I trying for a given passed in disk device path (NOT the mounted path), get the capacity of the disk and the amount of free space.

So I am using the boost space( path ) method and it returns a space_info structure.

If I pass in the actual mounted file system path I get the correct number.

However I really need to use the disk device path and that returns the incorrect numbers.

Is there some way programmatically to convert the disk device id path to an actual mounted disk path?

Or is there a different way I should try to get disk information if I only know the mounted path.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Should be possible to find that information in the `/proc` or `/sys` filesystems. And there's probably some IOCTL to get it as well.

Comment: I found a mounts file in the /proc directory. Will this directory / file always be on every Linux system.?  What do you mean byIOCTL ??

Comment: `/proc/mounts` only list mounted filesystems, and not any statistic about them. Try looking in `/sys/block` instead. With IOCTL I mean [the `ioctl` system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html).

Comment: I suspect you have a thinko there. `/dev/sda` probably holds `/dev/sda1`, perhaps `/dev/sda2` or even more partitions. That is to say, unless they're raid partitions, in which case you won't have a `/dev/sda1`. Free space is effectively a property of a volume (partition), not the disk.

Comment: I tried using the partion names for the boost space calls for /dev/sda1 but it just gave me 1gig capacity which is wrong

Comment: I will be using it for a raid device in the future